# How can I specify the base for Math.log() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math, logarithm

I need a `log` function for JavaScript, but it needs to be base 10. I can't see any listing for this, so I'm assuming it's not possible. Are there any math wizards out there who know a solution for this?

Comment: There is a Math.log10() method ever since ECMAScript 2015 for those who come here later on.

Answer (score 356, accepted):

**"Change of Base" Formula / Identity**

> The numerical value for logarithm to the base 10 can be calculated
>   with the following identity.

[image: Logarithm for base 10]

---

Since `Math.log(x)` in JavaScript returns the natural logarithm of `x` (same as *ln(x)*), for base 10 you can divide by `Math.log(10)` (same as *ln(10)*):

```
function log10(val) {
  return Math.log(val) / Math.LN10;
}
```

`Math.LN10` is a built-in precomputed constant for `Math.log(10)`, so this function is essentially identical to:

```
function log10(val) {
  return Math.log(val) / Math.log(10);
}
```

Comment: In fact, any base can be used, not just *e* or 2, as long as both logarithms use the same base.

Comment: Added an image with the formula and linked to Wikipedia if you don't mind.

Comment: Wasteful to calculate Math.log(10) each time. 
Unnecessary to precalculate and store since Math defines this constant already http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_ln10.asp

Comment: For bases other than 10, scroll down to [CMS's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3019319/568458). If scrolling down and reading an answer sounds like hard work, basic principle is `return Math.log(n) / Math.log(base);`

Comment: I've noticed some potential room for error here, probably having to do with floating point math. I just tried the function above with a value of 1000 in node, and got a result of 2.9999999999999996. (Although other numbers I tried, such as 10, 100, and even 10000, came out with correct values.)

Comment: It's now present in all popular browsers except IE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log10

Comment: Might be useful to add `Number.EPSILON` to the result to curb rounding errors. So that `Math.floor(Math.log(1000) / Math.log(10) + Number.EPSILON) === 3` is `true`.

Comment: While mathematically correct, since JS uses IEEE754 standard for math, there are rounding errors with floating point arithmetics. Therefore, log base mathematics won't work reliably in JS (or any language that uses IEEE574 for that matter).

`Math.log(9) / Math.log(3)` won't be an integer. And adding `Number.EPSILON` as suggested in the previous comment doesn't solve all cases.

Comment: @MichaelKariv "Wasteful" yet inconsequential in many applications. I think it's a mistake that `Math.LN10` is included in Javascript, b/c that's just one more thing for a programmer to remember. It's trivial to calculate it yourself: `const lg10 = Math.log(10)`, and at least here you don't have to remember more stuff

Answer (score 71):

Easy, just change the base by dividing by the log(10). There is even a constant to help you

```
Math.log(num) / Math.LN10;
```

which is the same as:

```
Math.log(num) / Math.log(10);
```

Answer (score 56):

You can simply divide the logarithm of your value, and the logarithm of the desired base, also you could override the `Math.log` method to accept an optional base argument:

```
Math.log = (function() {
  var log = Math.log;
  return function(n, base) {
    return log(n)/(base ? log(base) : 1);
  };
})();

Math.log(5, 10);
```

Answer (score 31):

```
const logBase = (n, base) => Math.log(n) / Math.log(base);
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base

Answer (score 18):

the answer here would cause obvious precision problem and is not reliable in some use cases

```
> Math.log(10)/Math.LN10
1

> Math.log(100)/Math.LN10
2

> Math.log(1000)/Math.LN10
2.9999999999999996

> Math.log(10000)/Math.LN10
4
```

Comment: Adjust precision with selective rounding:

   `(Math.round(Math.log(1000) / Math.LN10 * 1e6) / 1e6)`

Answer (score 16):

```
Math.log10 = function(n) {
    return (Math.log(n)) / (Math.log(10));
}
```

Then you can do

```
Math.log10(your_number);
```

**NOTE:** Initially I thought to do `Math.prototype.log10 = ...` to do this, but user [CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5445/cms) pointed out that Math doesn't work this way, so I edited out the `.prototype` part.

Comment: [`Math`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Math) is an object, not a constructor function, therefore it doesn't have a `prototype` property.

Comment: thanks CMS. Proves one should test things before one feels "inspired." I'll go back to the drawing pad.

Comment: Just remove the `.prototype` part ;)

Answer (score 9):

FF 25+ supports a [`Math.log10`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log10) method. You may to use polyfill:

```
if (!Math.log10) Math.log10 = function(t){ return Math.log(t)/Math.LN10; };
```

MDN lists the [supported browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log10#Browser_compatibility).

> #### Desktop Browsers
>
> ```
> Chrome    Firefox (Gecko) Internet Explorer   Opera   Safari
> 38        25 (25)         Not supported       25      7.1
> ```
>
> #### Mobile Browsers
>
> ```
> Android         Chrome for Android    Firefox Mobile (Gecko)  IE Mobile      Opera Mobile    Safari Mobile
> Not supported   Not supported         25.0 (25)               Not supported  Not supported   iOS 8
> ```

Answer (score 3):

`Math.log10(x)`

The top answer is fine for an arbitrary base, but the question is regarding log base 10, and `Math.log10(x)` has been [standard across all browsers since 2015.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log10)*

**Except IE, if that's important to you for some reason.*

Answer (score 0):

If you have a number x, then use of `Math.log(x)` would essentially be lnx.

To convert it to a base other than e, you can use the following function :

```
function(x){ return Math.log(x)/Math.log(10); }
```

Answer (score 0):

For base 10 use `Math.log10()`.

See docs at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log10