# How can you perform varying base logarithmic functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logarithm

This problem is being asked with a node.js server in mind, but I stated the question as "javascript" because I will likely use this same logic for a client-side script, as well.

Here's the problem: given a set of x values, y needs to scale in a logarithmic way. The Math object performs a natural log [`ln(x)`], but does not provide an interface for specifying the base of the logarithm.

For a specific example, I need to find the following:

`log[512](2)`

Which should return .1111~

However, I do not see an interface that allows me to accomplish this, nor can I seem to find a library that exposes an option for the log's base. Surely this is a common problem and has a solution, but my searching has only found solutions for different/unrelated problems. Ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Any way to specify the base of math.log() in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019278)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [logarithm base change formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base):

```
log[a](n) = log[b](n) / log[b](a)
```

So in order to get log(2) base 512, use:

```
function log(b, n) {
    return Math.log(n) / Math.log(b);
}

alert(log(2, 512));
```

Note that `Math.log` above uses the natural log base; i.e., it would be written as `ln` mathematically.

Comment: the javascript function would look like `function log(base, number) { return Math.ln(number) / Math.ln(base); }`

Comment: So, this ended up being a math question. Man, it's been years since I've had to work logarithm problems. Thanks for the quick fix.

Comment: Very true, I forgot this was a JS question and not just a math one. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I just tried it out and it really should be `log`, not `ln`. I feel awful for letting this sit for over a year.

Comment: Has it been a year already? Wow. Seems like I just asked this a month ago. On a side note, it's strange how log refers to ln in programming; I'm sure it has caught up quite a few programmers in frustrated debugging. The fact that you have to go out of your way to find or recreate log[10] can be annoying.

Answer (score 5):

I found this answer as a first result in google today, and if anyone else finds it too, there's a small mistake. The correct version is as follows:

```js
function log(b, n) {  
    return Math.log(n) / Math.log(b);  
}
```

Comment: Well, it's fixed now... :-)