# why javascript ln is called log?

Tags: javascript, math

I just fight few hours trying to implement some physics calculation.

Then, I discovered everything was wrong, just because Math.log is not about log10 but ln.

I would expect `Math.ln() = ln` and `Math.log() = log10`. But absolutly not `Math.log() = ln` !!!

Why did they make it so confusing ?

Comment: This isn't really the kind of question for this site.

Comment: Because programmers are not mathematicians!

Comment: See this question for additional information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019278/any-way-to-specify-the-base-of-math-log-in-javascript

Comment: The e-logarithm is the natural logarithm and has much more elegant properties. We humans only use the 10-logarithm because we (usually) have 10 fingers... By that logic, it is the right thing to reserve `log` for the *truly* natural logarithm.

Comment: @Antony Actually, mathematicians use `log` for the natural logarithm, so that's something programmers have in common with mathematicians.

Comment: I can relate with your frustration man!

Answer (score 6):

Mathematicians commonly use logarithms with a base of `e` for convenience. They don't take into account the distinction between the natural log and the common log; they use a single logarithmic function `log` because in higher mathematics the use of Euler constant is very common.

Answer (score 4):

This is the convention in academic mathematics.