# Why do I get a length of 5 logged to the console when the length of the number is greater than 21?

Tags: javascript

```
var metricUnits = function(num) {

console.log(num.toString().length);

};

// This works, gives me 21
metricUnits(900000000000000000000);

// But this fails, gives me 5
metricUnits(9000000000000000000000);
```

When I invoke this function, 21 is logged to the console. However, when I add one or more zeros to the end of my input argument, 5 is printed to the console?! Why is this?

Comment: Try printing `num.toString()`. It should make things clearer :)

Comment: The output of `toString` with one more zero is `9e+21` which has a length of 5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you logged the result to the console it would be obvious. Above a certain limit, numbers are represented by scientific notation (when asking for their string representation). In your second case,  `9e+21` - 5 characters

Details of the limit can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin) question.

Answer (score 2):

When the number is too big, it ends up looking like: `9e+21`

So, when you do `.toString().length`, it will return 5.

An alternative way to count the number of digits to avoid the problem is:

```js
var metricUnits = function(num) {
  log(Math.floor(Math.log10(num)) + 1);
};

log("900000000000000000000 =>");
metricUnits(900000000000000000000);  // 21
log("9000000000000000000000 =>");
metricUnits(9000000000000000000000); // 22

function log(msg) {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
    "beforeend",
    "<pre>" + msg + "</pre>"
  );
}
```

Comment: Sadly, `Math.log10` isn't in [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/), not even the [upcoming spec](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html). Chrome and Firefox both have it; IE11 doesn't.

Comment: I guess we'll have to work around it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019278/how-can-i-specify-the-base-for-math-log-in-javascript