# Why is my javascript returning an incorrect value for Math.log?

Tags: javascript, math

My script:

```
var dblTemp = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 12000000000; //378432000000000000

return Math.log(dblTemp);
```

My expected value is `~17.5779878529829`.  I derive this by using my Windows Calculator to enter `378432000000000000` then press the `log` function.

If I run my script, it returns `~40.47481279510905`.

Am I using `Math.log` incorrectly? Why is my javascript returning an incorrect value for `Math.log`?

Comment: To watch out for overflow, doing Math.log10(365) + Math.log10(24 ) +Math.log10(60 ) +Math.log10(60 ) +Math.log10(12000000000) is better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculator calculates the **base 10** logarithm. `Math.log` calculates the [**base `e`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm) logarithm.

If you want the same result as your calculator, use `Math.log10`:

```js
var dblTemp = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 12000000000; //378432000000000000

document.write(Math.log10(dblTemp));
```

If your runtime doesn't support `Math.log10` you can [define the function yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019278/how-can-i-specify-the-base-for-math-log-in-javascript):

```
function log10(val) {
  return Math.log(val) / Math.LN10;
}
```

[Math.LN10](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/LN10) is supported by all browsers.

Comment: Is there an alternate option to make this IE compatible?

Comment: Not Edge; so, anything older than IE11. `Math.LN10` isn't supported on my version of IE either.  I think I found the alternative by creating a function in place of `Math.log10`, `return Math.log(x) / 2.302585092994046`.

Comment: I forgot that `log10` was ES6. See the updated answer.

Comment: I was mistaken.  Thanks.

Comment: @CIA `return Math.log(x) / Math.log(10)` would be a more readable version if `Math.LN10` isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Math.log()` uses a base of `e` while your calculator is using base `10`. So you want to use `Math.log10`:

```
return Math.log10(dblTemp); // 17.577987852982993
```