# Algorithm to set axis labels to multiples of 5 or 10 in Core Plot

Tags: objective-c, ios, algorithm, math, core-plot

What algorithm or formula would you recommend to set the labels on the y-axis to multiples of 5 or 10 in CorePlot?

I basically want to get even numbering, for instance: 5, 10, 15, 20 or 100, 105, 110, 115... and set the maximum number of y-labels to 10.

Any ideas would be welcome! Thank you!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm for "nice" grid line intervals on a graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361681/algorithm-for-nice-grid-line-intervals-on-a-graph)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is controlled by the "labeling policy". You have several choices:

```
typedef enum _CPTAxisLabelingPolicy {
    CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone,              ///< No labels provided; user sets labels and tick locations.
    CPTAxisLabelingPolicyLocationsProvided, ///< User sets tick locations; axis makes labels.
    CPTAxisLabelingPolicyFixedInterval,     ///< Fixed interval labeling policy.
    CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic,         ///< Automatic labeling policy.
    CPTAxisLabelingPolicyEqualDivisions     ///< Divide the plot range into equal parts.
} CPTAxisLabelingPolicy;
```

If you know how far apart you want the tick marks, keep the default labeling policy (fixed interval) and set the `majorIntervalLength` to the desired interval. You could also use the automatic policy to let Core Plot pick the intervals. Use the `preferredNumberOfMajorTicks` property to give it a hint about how many tick marks to make.