# Picking "nice" numbers on graph markers/rules out of given set of rule positions

Tags: c++, graph, modulo, ieee-754

Using code from [question about picking nice rule/marker interval](https://stackoverflow.com/q/361681/607407) I created a code that renders rules on the graph.

[image: image description]

It has nice intervals of `0.1`. But I don't like to display all the numbers, instead, I'd like to increase rule density but only mark every few rules. Like this:

[image: image description]

I created an algorithm that does so by multiplying rule interval by a number, then highlighting rules that can be divided by the result. I use [`fmod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) because the values can of course be float:

```
    // See https://stackoverflow.com/q/361681/607407 for algorithms
    double rule_spacing = tickSpacing(pixels_per_rule);
    // These are the highlighted rules - currently it should be every 2nd rule
    double important_steps = rule_spacing*2.0;
    // Getting the stard draw offset which should be bellow bottom graph corner
    double start = graph_math::roundTo(begin.y, rule_spacing);
    LOGMTRTTIINFO("Legend from "<<start<<" to "<<values.maxYValue<<" by "<<rule_spacing<<", numbers: "<<important_steps<<'\n');
    //Loop until on top
    while(start<=values.maxYValue) {
        int y = pixelForYValue(start);
        // HERE: calculating whether this is the NTH rule!
        float remainder = fmod(start, important_steps);
        LOGMTRTTIINFO("        "<<" legend at px"<<y<<" with marker "<<start<<" Marker remainder:"<<remainder<<'\n');
        if(remainder==0) {
            // Draw highlighted rule
        }
        else {
            // Draw normal rule
        }
    }
```

The problem is that `fmod` is rather unreliable. Check this log output where values that **can be divided by `0.1`** return `0.1` in `fmod`:

```
Legend from 95.9 to 96.3097 by 0.05, numbers (important_steps): 0.1
         legend at px240 with marker 95.9 Marker remainder:3.60822e-16
         legend at px211 with marker 95.95 Marker remainder:0.05
         legend at px181 with marker 96 Marker remainder:0.1
         legend at px152 with marker 96.05 Marker remainder:0.05
         legend at px123 with marker 96.1 Marker remainder:0.1
         legend at px93 with marker 96.15 Marker remainder:0.05
         legend at px64 with marker 96.2 Marker remainder:0.1
         legend at px35 with marker 96.25 Marker remainder:0.05
         legend at px5 with marker 96.3 Marker remainder:0.1
```

I guess I could outsmart this by adding `important_steps==remainder`, but isn't the function flawed if it actually returns the denominator, which should never happen for `%` (modulo)?

How do I overcome this with sufficient certainty? [Testing snippet available.](http://ideone.com/EHPeyM)

Btw, this is how nicely it works once the `important_steps` is greater or equal to `1`:

[image: image description]

Comment: Would you be open to switch to [decimal arithmetic](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14096026/335858) that eliminates `fmod`'s issue with `0.1`?

Comment: Yeah, but I am not sure how to efficiently calculate required multiply to turn `double` into `long` (eg. `10`, `100`, `1000` and so on).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best way to do this is to round to integers, and then check the difference, like this:

```
float quotient = start / important_step;
int quot_int = round(quotient);
if (abs(quotient - quot_int) < 1e-10)
{
    // Draw highlighted rule
}
else
{
    // Draw normal rule
}
```

EDIT: function round

```
int round(double x){return floor(x + 0.5);}
```

Comment: Are you sure this will work for super tiny numbers? I mean 1e-10 is not that small.

Comment: This 1e-10 is small enough, unless your `important_steps` is `1e10` times `rule_spacing`. Note that it is the QUOTIENT that we are rounding. Why don't you try it?

Comment: It doesn't work, I can't figure why but the `abs( ... )` is always zero. I tried to declare `quit_int` as float to prevent some unwanted implicit cast but it didn't help. I created testing snippet here: http://ideone.com/EHPeyM

Comment: The problem is probably that `round` is not defined. You can add your own `round` function (see my edit).